# angular js - ng-view - ng-route - condition when loading a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller, routes

I'm building a simple web application that involves 3 languages, I want to change the content from a block of text dynamically using partial html files with the language selected; Based of what i've researched, doesn't seem too difficult for me to set up the ng-view functionality, from w3schools:
[ng-routing - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp)

What I want to achieve is something that may be pretty simple but i can't get my head around it, I'll try to represent my idea using the same block of code that I took from w3schools ( the next code of course wouldn't work, but i hope it can explains my idea ) :

```
  var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
   app.config(function($routeProvider) {
       // declare variable to evaluate 
       var lang = "(dynamic value)"; // this value will be set dynamically.
       $routeProvider
       // condition if variable value is "es" 
       if (lang == "es") { 
       .when("/es", {
           templateUrl : "es.htm"
       })
      } 
      // else if , load the other language
      else if (lang == "ja") {
       .when("/ja", {
           templateUrl : "ja.htm"
       })
      }
      // if the value is none of above, then load the "default" one
      else { 
       .when("/en", {
           templateUrl : "en.htm"
       });
     }
   });
```

I hope my question isn't too confusing, I did research about $resolve and also $route callbacks but i just can't figure them out, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Do the routes need to be set in app.config or can this logic be done later inside a controller?

Comment: @stevenelberger No, it can be done later inside a controller, this condition would only be checked on load, the first time the user enters the website, after that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This logic can be configured in a controller like so using the `ngInclude` directive:

**Controller:**

```
app.module("myApp")
   .controller("myController", 
   function() {
       var self = this;
       self.lang = "(dynamic value)";
       self.templatePath = "";
       if (lang === "es") {
           self.templatePath = "(es path here)";
       } else if (lang === "ja") {
           self.templatePath = "(ja path here)";
       } else {
           self.templatePath = "(en path here)";
       }
   });
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="myController as myCtrl">
    <div ng-include="myCtrl.templatePath"></div>
</div>
```

This can also be done with `$routeProvider` via `templateUrl` as a function, e.g.:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/:lang/somePage', {
            templateUrl: function(urlAttr) {
                if (urlAttr.lang === "es") {
                    return "/pathForEs";
                } else if (urlAttr.lang === "ja") {
                    return "/pathForJa";
                } else {
                    return "/pathForEn";
                }
            },
            controller: "somePageController"
        }).
        otherwise({
            routeTo: "/",
        });
});
```

Comment: For the ng-include way, is there a way i could also make some form of "navigation" , so, if the user gets into the site with a value of "es" , and gets the "/es-path" then the user can change it either to "/ja-path" or "/en-path", which /en-path should be the default; i think i had to say that i'm getting these values with js, like this:

var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
var lang = language.substr(0, 2);

is there a way to make a navigation to accomplish this?

Comment: You could have a link in your view with an ng-click directive that links to a function in the controller which changes the path (e.g., ng-click="myCtrl.changePath()")

Comment: I'm trying to make it work, but it doesn't seem to be, I want to get this value: <br/>
`var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language; var lang = language.substr(0, 2);`
then based of the value obtained (which is a 2 letter string "es" , "ja", "en" ) set the content of the partial based of it, i'm trying to us the ngInclude way, but the scope doesn't seem to be getting the language value, nohting is showing in the console, therefore nothing is set or showing, not sure how the code should look at is "final form"

Comment: Trying to reference window in a controller should be done through the $window service. As per the original question, I think my answer has provided a sufficient solution so please mark it as accepted and if there are other problems you will need to create a new question on StackOverflow. Thanks! :)